# Maven won't run my project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

So whatever I do I can't get my project to run on my mac. But the project seems to run fine on my colleagues pc's. Is there something i'm not seeing in my pom file? I keep getting this error,

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
>   (default-cli) on project got-team20: Command execution failed. Process
>   exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

I have maven 3.5.0 installed on my mac, but i don't know if that can be a issue? I have also tried three different ide's, so the problem is not there.

My pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.gameoftrades</groupId>
    <!-- Change Me -->
    <artifactId>got-team20</artifactId> <!-- got-teamNN -->
    <!-- --> 
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Game of Trades Student Starter Kit</name>
    <description>Student starter kit for Game of Trades</description>
    <inceptionYear>2016</inceptionYear>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <organization>
        <name>42 BV</name>
        <url>http://blog.42.nl/</url>
    </organization>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <got.version>0.3.0</got.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gameoftrades</groupId>
            <artifactId>gameoftrades-library</artifactId>
            <version>${got.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
      <snapshotRepository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement> 

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the full error i have when i run it with the -e switch.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on
>   project got-team20: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java are missing or invalid
>   -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java
>   (default-cli) on project got-team23: The parameters 'mainClass' for
>   goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java are missing or
>   invalid...

So i guess something is wrong with the plugins i am using.

Comment: show the full error message

Comment: Did you run with the `-e` switch as suggested, to get more information?

Comment: The maven exec plugin fails.  That plugin is not in your pom.xml.  Find where it is in your project tree.

Comment: Can you share the `mvn` command you're using for execution?

Comment: @MickMnemonic I'm using mvn e- exec:java

Comment: Are you passing the main class as a parameter somehow? That's the only mandatory parameter for the plugin.